# How to traverse through the auto key generated by firebase push() in React Native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a search that queries the discogs api for Albums. when I swipe the Album it gets pushed into the realtime database. Firebase auto generates keys for each item pushed which is great, but I am not sure how to handle these keys. How do I get the image url into my require statement? I

here's the function that pushes to the database.

```
saveToCollection() {
    const myFirebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
    myFirebaseRef.push({
      albums: `${this.props.album.cover}`
    });
}
```

[image: this is the auto generated key by firebase]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Update with code from comments:

```
componentWillMount() {
    const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
    const albumRef = rootRef.child('albums');
    albumRef.once('value', (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
            var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
            var childData = childSnapshot.val(); // ... this.setState({albums: childKey.childData}) }); }); }// This is just a sample script. Paste your real code (javascript or HTML) here.

            if ('this_is' == /an_example/) {
                of_beautifier();
            } else {
                var a = b ? (c % d) : e[f];
            }
```

Comment: To get the data from the database, you attach a listener and then handle the data snapshot. For an example, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events

Comment: That seems like a *very* different error. Based on what you posted, I can't tell where the error comes from.

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate over the firebase auto generated keys using for...in and push each value in into an array then use the Mustache {{#.}} ... {{/.}} tag pair to iterate over each object in the array.

```
let arr = [];

for(let autoKey in childData){
    arr.push(childData[autoKey]);
}

let tpl = '{{#.}} {{albums}} {{/.}}';

Mustache.render(tpl, arr);
```